# Recovery From Failure in DBMS

Tags: postgresql

we consider a recovery from failure on running in the following way:

initially log analysis allows to determine the dirty pages

The second phase is to redo all operations validated before failure that are not properly written to the database files.

The third phase is to undo transactions in progress at the time of the outage, which had already made updates in the database files

```
1. T1:begin
 2. T1:write(P1)
 3. T1:write(P2)
 4. T2:begin
 5. T2:write(P3)
 6. T1:write(P5)
 7. T1:commit
 8. T3:begin
 9. T3:write(P2)
 10. T2:write(P1)
 11. T4:begin
 12. T4:write(P4)
 13. T2:abort
 14. T3:write(P3)
 *Failure*
```

After the analysis phase what are the active transactions and dirty pages.
What operations are beings replayed (REDO) and what order.
What operations are beings canceled (UNDO) and what order.